# ¿Cómo ejectuar query sql con suma en dos tablas distintas con minor fecha?

Tags: sql

Necesito sumar datos de dos tablas distintas,Pero mi query está mal.

**1 - Suma por tabla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2 - Tabla DOG**

```
CODIGO;RAZA;FECHA_NASC;VALOR
1;CANICHE;2020-09-30;150.00
1;POMERANIA;2020-11-18;150.00
```

**3 - Tabla VENTA**

```
CODIGO;NRO;FECHA_VENTA;VALOR
1;1;2020-10-01;100.00
1;2;2020-11-01;150.00
1;3;2020-12-01;150.00
```

**4 - Query com valor total**

```
SELECT 'VALOR AGRUPADO'[VALOR AGRUPADO], 
V.CODIGO,COUNT(V.CODIGO)[CANT VENTAS],SUM(V.VALOR)[VALOR_VENTAS],
COUNT(D.RAZA)[CANT RAZA],MIN(D.FECHA_NASC)[MENOR_FECHA],
SUM(D.VALOR)[VALOR_RAZA]
FROM VENTA V
INNER JOIN DOG D WITH(NOLOCK) ON D.CODIGO = V.CODIGO
WHERE V.CODIGO IN (1)
GROUP BY V.CODIGO
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias por la ayuda
Jose Bonfim

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la pregunta esta un tanto escueta, sin embargo, veo que entre ambas tablas no hay una llave primaria (o si la hay, debe ser compuesta) por lo que al momento de hacer el **INNER JOIN** estas haciendo un producto cartesiano (ya que todos tienen código 1), ya que cruzas todas las filas de la tabla **DOG** con las filas de la tabla **VENTA**. Es por eso que todo te sale el doble.

Una posible solución es cambiar la estructura de la tablas para mapear de mejor manera la relación, definiendo la llave primaria en la tabla **DOG** (es decir un campo o conjunto de campos que identifiquen cada fila como única) de manera en que pueda relacionar por esa llave la la **VENTA** con el perro de la venta. Y poner la referencia en la tabla **VENTA**, mas o menos de esta manera (***ojo que estoy inventando la relación entre cada venta y el perro ya que no conozco tu base de datos***):

```
CODIGO;RAZA;FECHA_NASC;VALOR
1;CANICHE;2020-09-30;150.00
2;POMERANIA;2020-11-18;150.00

CODIGO;NRO;FECHA_VENTA;VALOR;CODIGO_DOG
1;1;2020-10-01;100.00;1
1;2;2020-11-01;150.00;2
1;3;2020-12-01;150.00;1
```

Con esto lo que hacemos es crear la relación entre cada venta y su perro.

De esta manera la consulta quedaría mas o menos así:

```
SELECT 'VALOR AGRUPADO'[VALOR AGRUPADO], 
V.CODIGO,COUNT(V.CODIGO)[CANT VENTAS],SUM(V.VALOR)[VALOR_VENTAS],
COUNT(D.RAZA)[CANT RAZA],MIN(D.FECHA_NASC)[MENOR_FECHA],
SUM(D.VALOR)[VALOR_RAZA]
FROM VENTA V
INNER JOIN DOG D WITH(NOLOCK) ON D.CODIGO = V.CODIGO_DOG
WHERE V.CODIGO IN (1)
GROUP BY V.CODIGO
```

Comment: Douglas Figueroa, gracias por contestarme. Lo he arreglado el ultimo imagen. El CODIGO en realidade sería GRUPO. Lo que deseo és : La cantidady suma del VALOR de la tabla RAZA y la suma y cantidad de la tabla VENTA. La llave de la relación es (CODIGO) = GRUPO. Mira que tiene el mismo valor =1.